# GTAG code equivalent of given ga_ code

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

On the `ga_` version of Google Analytics I use this code to improve my bounce rate:

```
setTimeout(‘_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘NoBounce’, ‘Over 20 seconds’])’,20000
```

But now I have to use the new version of Google Analytics, GTAG.

What is the equivalent of the old `ga_` code for GTAG?